# Clickonce authentication proxy

Tags: windows, deployment, installation

Someone know if there is a way to make clickonce to work behinda a authentication proxy?

Comment: Check this question :

How can I use my Proxy credentials when installing a Clickonce application(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126504/how-can-i-use-my-proxy-credentials-when-installing-a-clickonce-application)

Answer (score 1):

Yes but it depends on the proxy. If you are using a proxy which requires a username and password you will need to jump through a couple of hoops.

Essentially there is a small bug with ClickOnce and authentication proxies but I do have a work around on my blog that allows you to update your application via ClickOnce but the catch is you need to get the initial install on the client machine. This can be done but either by doing the initial install via a CD or from a local network share.

[ClickOnce updates via authentication proxy](http://bronumski.blogspot.com/2009/06/clickonce-updates-via-authentication.html)